# Drawing on Canvas below inflated layout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-canvas

I have a camera surface view screen on which I am drawing some markers. I have a Navigation drawer also on this screen. So my problem is that the markers are drawn above the navigation drawer instead of showing under the navigation drawer. The side menu is shown by inflating a layout. So how to achieve this?

Comment: Show some code or your layout XML. The item with the highest Z-ordering ("the one that's on top") has to be inflated last. Which basically means - prepare your markers before inflating the navigation drawer, or inflate the drawer after initializing your markers.

Comment: extend SurfaceView or create custom View over it and then draw anything in onDraw method. https://github.com/kirvis250/Polygon-convex-hull : Look for file GrapicView.java as example.